# How to match a word from string and retrieve data in SQL Query and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySql Table just like this

```
Brand 
--------
Honda
Sozuki
Oddi
.
.
.
```

Now there is an dynamic array in PHP :

```
$brand = ["Sozuki","Honda"]
```

The Question is how to retrieve data that matches the word in above array. I tried this :

```
$qry = 'select * from brand where brand Like '% $brand[0] %' and '% $brand[1] %';
```

It works fine but what would I do if I have no specific length of array, you can say dynamic array.
Any solution will be appreciated Thanks

Comment: loop through your array and build like query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$qry = "select * from brand where brand ";
$i=1;
$count = count($brand); 
foreach($brand as $v) {
  $a = ($i < $count ? 'and' : '');
  $qry .=  " Like '% $v %'  $a ";
  $i++;
}
echo $qry;
```

Comment: I wonder will it comply with SQL syntax accepted by the engine.

Comment: @Vesper is there any issue?

Comment: This is awesome Rakesh very nice.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Maybe it's just me, I've yet to face an SQL syntax of multiple pattern matches with "like" condition. I have only seen syntax like `where field like "%string%" or field like "%otherstring%"`, not `where field like "%string%" and "%otherstring%"`. So issues can arise, if this syntax is not valid.

Comment: @Vesper i agree with you but answer gives according to OP's question, it's depend on what your requirements

Comment: A downside of this aproach is that it will only have limited use in case of a user input scenario

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't you rather use OR instead of AND?

If so use something like this (note: **UNTESTED**):

```
<?php
$brands     = array(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9);
$inQuery = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($brands), '?'));

$db = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare(
    'SELECT *
     FROM brand
     WHERE brand IN(' . $inQuery . ')'
);

foreach ($brands as $k => $brand)
    $stmt->bindValue(($k+1), $brand);

$stmt->execute();

// Or simply $stmt->execute($brands);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$qry = 'select * from brand where brand Like ';
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($brands)-1; $i++) {
     $qry .= "'%" . $brand[$i] . "%'";
     if ($i < sizeof($brands) - 2) {
         $qry .= ' AND ';
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$i=0;
$brand=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Honda","Suzuki");
$qry = 'select * from brand where brand Like '% $brand[i] `enter code here`%'';
$i++;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should define array as

```
$brand = array("Sozuki","Honda");
```

so then you can use `$brand[0]`, etc ...

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM brand WHERE brand LIKE '%{$brand[0]}%' AND '%{$brand[1])%'";
```

Comment: This is not an answer what OP asked for

Comment: That's what he did with `$brand = ["Sozuki","Honda"]`. And this is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: The array is said to be dynamic, so you can't set a fixed amount of items to put into the `$qry`.